# Can I make adblockers see element as a ad

Tags: html, adblock

Is there a way I can mark a element as a ad so that adblock will hide it? I have a user upset because what he considers a ad isnt blocked by his ad blocker.

Comment: Technical things aside but if it's *the users adblocker* and *the users objection* why is it your problem?

Comment: Maybe looking from the opposite direction like [How to deal with AdBlock blocking non-ad elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43998076/205233) offers a clue (blacklisted CSS selectors?)

Comment: I'd still say this is simply a matter of asking the user to right-click the offending element and choose to block this element ... unless this is objectively indecent content and this is far from a technical issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So adblock works by searching through the scripts before load and removing anything that matches a list of known ads.

Technically all you would have to do is search for this element and add a class that would be picked up by the normal ad blocker.

```js
//get the elements you're looking for, turn into NodeList
  const makeAd = document.querySelectorAll(".the-element-youre-looking-for");
    
//function for adding a class called ".adContent"
  const addAds = (currentNode) => {
  currentNode.classlist.add('.adContent');

//iterating through each of the possible items in the NodeList
for(const i of makeAd) {
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {addAds( makeAd[i] );}
)};
```